# Qt 5.5 Mingw (gcc 4.9.2) compiling but unable to run project

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

I'm quite new to Qt and I'm facing some difficulties running a Qt 5.5 project under Qt Creator using Mingw 4.9.2 on Windows 7. I can compile it without any error but when I try to run it nothing happens, Qt Creator just freeze and I have to kill it. I also tried to start it manually from cmd with the same result. More informations :

- I installed both Qt and Mingw from Qt's official website installer
- I added to my global Path the following lines :

  - C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin;
  - C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin;
  - C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin;
- I ran this project under Ubuntu 14.04 (gcc 4.8.4) without any issue

Here is my .pro file :

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = SmashReader
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    player.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    player.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

# Opencv Library
INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\build\include
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\lib\libopencv_core300.dll.a
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\lib\libopencv_imgproc300.dll.a
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\lib\libopencv_highgui300.dll.a
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\lib\libopencv_videoio300.dll.a
```

I'm also trying to use OpenCV lib, but I have the same problem on another project without it so I'm assuming it does not come from here.

When I hit the "run" button, the compilation output gives me this :

```
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Théo/Documents/Programmation/SmashReader'
mingw32-make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Théo/Documents/Programmation/SmashReader'
```

And then Qt Creator doesn't respond anymore.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The output is ok. mingw just recognizes that your project was already build and thus has nothing to do. The error is propably somewhere in your application. Have you tried running some other project with mingw (e.g. one of Qts examples)

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

I tried with Qt's examples (gui) and had the same problem... :/

Comment: Well in this case it seems your mingw (or the Qt-libs for mingw) are broken. Try reinstalling it. If your lucky, that will fix the problem

Comment: Well I'm working with a fresh reinstallation of Qt/Mingw, but I will try it.

It appears that I have the same result with another kit using Visual C++ compiler so it might not be because of Mingw.

I'll keep searching.

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but could it be that it's using binaries from `C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin` instead of `C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin`?